# Ways to color four walls using four colors s. t. no two adjacent walls have the same color, rotations not being equivalent?

Tags: combinatorics

A room has four walls. In how many different ways can you
color the four walls, using colors from the set {Red, Green, Blue,
Yellow}, such that no two adjacent walls have the same color? Considering every wall different so rotations are not equivalent.

I am getting $64$ with help of cases

- with one color no coloring possible
- with two colors it is $\binom{4}{2}\cdot 2$
- with three colors it is $\binom{4}{3}\cdot3\cdot4$
- with four colors it is $\binom{4}{4}\cdot4$

so I get $12 + 48  + 4 = 64$ possible colorings.
Please clarify with cases or suggest any other method.

Comment: Are two colorings considered to be equivalent if one can be obtained from the other by rotation?  Also, please edit your question to show your work since that makes it easier for readers to detect any errors you may have made.

Comment: I get either 84 or 24 depending on if you consider them equivalent under rotation. So either you or me made a mistake somewhere. Could you expand your question with the exact calculation you did? The method you describe should give the correct answer (I think 84) if done precisely. And you can write `$\binom{4}{2}\cdot 2$` to get something like $\binom{4}{2}\cdot 2$, which I think is more easily readable.

Comment: In the 4-colour case you should have $\binom{4}{4}\cdot4!=1\cdot24$ ways.

Answer (score 1):

As Jaap Scherphuis pointed out in the comments, there are $4! = 24$ ways to paint the walls with four different colors since there are four ways to select which wall will be blue, three ways to select which wall will be green, two ways to select which wall will be red, and one way to select which wall will be yellow.

With three different colors, there are $4$ ways to select the color that will be used twice, $2$ ways to select the pair of opposite walls on which those colors will appear, $\binom{3}{2}$ ways to select the two colors that will appear on one wall each, and $2!$ ways to paint the remaining two walls with those colors, giving
$$\binom{4}{1}\binom{2}{1}\binom{3}{2}2!$$
such colorings, which agrees with your count.

With two different colors, there are $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to select the two colors that will be used and $2!$ ways to paint each of those colors on pairs of opposite walls.  Hence, there are
$$\binom{4}{2}2$$
such colorings, which agrees with your count.

Hence, there are
$$4! + \binom{4}{1}\binom{2}{1}\binom{3}{2}2! + \binom{4}{2}2!$$
ways to color the four walls of the room with no two adjacent walls having the same color under the assumption that two colorings that can be obtained from each other by rotation are not considered to be equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simpler way to count them, using only two cases.

Colour two opposite walls first.
If you choose different colours, then you have $4\cdot3$ choices for them, followed by $2\cdot2 $ choices for the other two walls, for a combined $4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot2=48$ ways to paint them.
If you choose a single colour for the opposite walls, a choice of $4$ colours, then you have $3\cdot3$ choices for the other two walls, for a combined $4\cdot3\cdot3=36$ ways to paint them.
This gives a total of $48+36=84$.

Answer (score 0):

Though there are 2 correct answers already, let me share my approach.
First of all, if rotations are not equivalent, it follows, that we have to consider permutations for patterns of length 4, which are joined subsets.

1. One color has a pattern of $A$, and in no way an adjacent can't be the same. Output: $0$.
2. Two colors have a pattern of $AB$, which can be joined to itself without having adjacents the same, and no other way $A$ and $B$ can be used without breaking the adjacency rule: this can be chosen $\binom{4}{2}$ ways, with a permutation of $2!$. Output: $12$.
3. Three colors have 2 patterns, one using only two colors first and another using three, both having the fourth color not equal to the first and last of the pattern:
   a) $ABA$, this can be chosen $\binom{4}{2}$ ways, with a permutation of $2!$, the 4th can be any of $\{C, D\}$ (no $B$, as there wouldn't be three colors used), multiplier of $2$. Output: $24$.
   b) $ABC$, this can be chosen $\binom{4}{3}$ ways, with a permutation of $3!$, the 4th can be any of $\{B, D\}$, multiplier of $2$. Output: $24$.
   a) + b) output: $48$.
4. Four colors have a pattern of $ABCD$: this can be chosen $\binom{4}{4}$ ways, with a permutation of $4!$. Output: $24$.